# Rails scope with joins in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I have an Order that has_many Jobs. How can I create a scope to return all the Orders where all the jobs in the Order have a status of 'Closed'?

ie: This should not return an Order that has multiple jobs and one is not closed; only return where every job in the order is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a scope to return all the Orders where all the jobs
>   in the Order have a status of 'Closed'?

This should do

```
scope :all_closed_jobs, -> { joins(:jobs).where('jobs.status = ?', 'closed') }
```

Comment: Thanks, look like I had a simple mix up in the joins